# Cant install Pyodbc and other python libraries

Tags: python, pyodbc, python-wheel

Hello i am trying (in windows) to install pyodbc for a work project. What could I do, I really need to work with this library. Also, I've tried to install it in other windows machines and it looks to work properly. I am getting this error

```
pip install pyodbc
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -ip (c:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.10\site-packages)
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.39.tar.gz (282 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pyodbc (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      WARNING: '' not a valid package name; please use only .-separated package names in setup.py
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310
      copying src\pyodbc.pyi -> build\lib.mingw_x86_64-cpython-310
      running build_ext
      building 'pyodbc' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have been searching for it online and nothing has worked out yet. Also I've reinstalled python.
Has anyone else got this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76079590/5320906) answer your question?