# When building a C++ python extension on windows I get the following error: --plat-name

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I want to create a Python library using C++ to speed up my simulations. In a certain directory, I have a file called simulation.cpp, one setup.py, and a pyproject.toml file. At the end of the simulation.cpp file I have written

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(simulator, m) {
    m.def("simulate", &simulate, "Simulate the system and return trajectory as a NumPy array.");}
```

Next, the setup.py file reads:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import pybind11

cpp_args = ['-std=c++11', '-stdlib=libc++']

sfc_module = Extension(
    'simulator',
    sources=['simulation.cpp'],
    include_dirs=[pybind11.get_include()],
    language='c++',
    extra_compile_args=cpp_args,
    )

setup(
    name='simulator',
    version='1.0',
    description='Python package with C++ extension (PyBind11)',
    ext_modules=[sfc_module],
)
```

And last but not least, the pyproject.toml file reads

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "pybind11"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

In this directory, I created an python virtual environment, installed pybind11 via pip, but when I want to install the package by entering

```
pip install .
```

I get the following error:

```
Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: simulator
  Building wheel for simulator (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for simulator (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [5 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_ext
      building 'simulator' extension
      error: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for simulator
Failed to build simulator
ERROR: Could not build wheels for simulator, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76079590/error-plat-name-must-be-one-of-win32-win-amd64-win-arm32-win-arm6

Comment: Didn't worked since my lib\python3.9\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py looks totally different. Also I am working on Windows so the second solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: both answers apply to windows...