# Error with cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz when performing pip install -r requirements.txt

Tags: distutils, requirements.txt, python-cffi

`Collecting cffi==1.15.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 45))
Using cached cffi-1.15.1.tar.gz (508 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [16 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in
File "", line 34, in
File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7tvsutzu\cffi_f224d2d0b6b44d45b77aab1b2eb9438b\setup.py", line 126, in
if sys.platform == "win32" and uses_msvc():
File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7tvsutzu\cffi_f224d2d0b6b44d45b77aab1b2eb9438b\setup.py", line 105, in uses_msvc
return config.try_compile('#ifndef _MSC_VER\n#error "not MSVC"\n#endif')
File "C:\name\dir\dirr\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\config.py", line 223, in try_compile
self._compile(body, headers, include_dirs, lang)
File "C:\name\dir\dirr\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_distutils\command\config.py", line 128, in _compile
self.compiler.compile([src], include_dirs=include_dirs)
File "C:\name\dir\dirr\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 343, in compile
self.initialize()
File "C:\name\dir\dirr\venv\lib\python3.10\site-packages\setuptools_distutils_msvccompiler.py", line 246, in initialize
raise DistutilsPlatformError(
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: --plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

Comment: The error [--plat-name must be one of ('win32', 'win-amd64', 'win-arm32', 'win-arm64')](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=plat-name+must+be+one+of+%28%27win32%27%2C+%27win-amd64%27%2C+%27win-arm32%27%2C+%27win-arm64%27%29) seems to be from MINGW or MSYS32. Is it what you use?

Comment: I believe so. I have a msys64 folder for C++ from school, and in it there's separate folders for mingw32 and mingw64.

Comment: In answers in the search thre're advice to use mingw-patched `setuptools` and don't upgrade it from PyPI as the standard `setuptools` doesn't work with MINGW/MSYS64.

Comment: Sorry could you elaborate more on this? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I don't know more than that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76882830/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/76221491/7976758 , https://packages.msys2.org/search?q=setuptools

Comment: I also have this problem, but I'm on plain Windows.  Python 3.10.12.